# Named Credentials access issue to customer Portal user

Tags: namedcredentials

- Named credentials developed for a Customer Portal working fine for Admins,
- but where as the customer portal users have access issues even after

  - adding the User to the Permission set and
  - adding the External Credential to the Profile under Enable External Credential Principal access.
- When ran the logic from  Execute Anonymous  window got the Status as 200

Am I missing any other step to give access?

Here is the error `System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "customerPortalCreds" might not exist`

Comment: Does running user have Read access to `UserExternalCredentials` ?

Comment: Thank you cropredy that helped. my question is well formed with necessary info not sure why it marked as negative.

Comment: N.B. I didn't downvote your question. Did adding R or View All to `UserExternalCredentials` solve your issue?

Comment: Read permission to the User External Credentials resolved the access issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the things you did, one easy thing to forget is to grant the running user (via Profile or Permission Set) CRUD access to `UserExternalCredentials`

The Doc reference for this is [User External Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_user_external_credentials.htm&type=5)

*N.B. The doc shows granting full CRUD to `UserExternalCredentials` but in my experience `View All` is sufficient when using Basic Authorization if that happens to be your use case.*